# Using authorization in ASP.NET, images not visible on page

Tags: forms-authentication

I have implemented forms authentication using the below mentioned code. My login URL is "Login.aspx". With these settings my site images do not get loaded on login.aspx.
However if I comment the `authorization` section the images are displayed.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="TBHFORMAUTH" defaultUrl="~/User/Default.aspx" loginUrl ="~/Login.aspx" cookieless="AutoDetect" />
</authentication>

<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Why this behaviour?

Comment: Did you check the path to the images in the html?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a separate Web.config file to the Images folder that does not need user control. The Web.config file should only contain the following to give full access:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
            <authorization>
               <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Another approach is if all pages that are limited by usercontrol are located in a sub folder (i.e. Users), then you can give full access in the main Web.config. and have a separate Web.config in the Users folder containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
            <authorization>
               <deny users="?" />
            </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```